# How to have fragments within tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-tabs

I have a basic tabbed setup, and the code is here:  https://github.com/epicfinley/Borden-App/tree/master/BGSapp/src/main/java/com/bordengrammar/bordengrammarapp

Now, i have the tabs working perfectly, and can swype in between parents students and home fragment.

But in the students tab i want to have multiple tabs, fragment 1 which will switch the other fragmet, fragment 2 to fragment 3,4,5,6 etc...

To help you see what i am trying to achieve, i have drawn up a what i am trying to acheive:
Landscape mode:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tY1s.png

Portrait mode:
imgur.com/ccEE2li

If you need more clarifcation, please do post a comment. If this is impossible or really hard to implement could you suggest a alternate route(tabs within tabs?)

Answer (score 0):

You may have to have the fragments communicate with the parent activity.
It is recommended to create an interface on the parent and then have the fragments call into the interface to indicate that the fragment containing 2 must now contain 3 (or 4,5,6 etc...).

See here for the dev docs regarding fragment to activity communication: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

For example, you could have an interface like:

```
public interface FragmentSwticher {
    public void showFragment(int id);
}
```

and then your parent activity could implement it, and your child fragments can call into it.

Comment: Ok, i get what you are saying a bit, but how would i do the fragments in the fragments depending on orientation and how to initialises the fragments? Sorry bit of a beginner here!

Comment: The way I understand it, you could create two FrameLayout objects in the layout (XML) for the parent activity; you can load whatever fragment you want into these layout objects. See http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html for details on using the FragmentManager to load fragments into these FrameLayouts. Then, using the interface method above, you could have one of your fragments ask the parent activity to change the fragment being shown in the FrameLayout. As for orientation, you can setup specific layouts for both portrait and landscape orientations.

Comment: Sorry, I know there is a lot of detail above, the android dev docs have some pretty good info about fragments. I would start by reading those start to end if you haven't already.